# Can I use webex to show app from a remote desktop connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, webex

I am working on a demo for a potential client and they want to run a webex meeting.

Right now we are testing with the following scenario.

- Machine A is in a lab and is running our app
- Machine B is elsewhere (a laptop) and we use remote desktop to connect to machine A and run software on it.

If we have a webex on machine B with other people can we show the apps from machine A to the webex participants?

EDIT:

To clarify - I am asking a specific question:

Can webex show a remote desktop of one of the participants if that is NOT the machine they are connecting to webex with?

Machine A has limited or restricted  internet access - that is one reason we are setting up like this.

Comment: I'm sorry -- I've never tried remote desktop over a web ex connection. Can someone help you test -- be the client and you run the remote desktop connection over it?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to test this with a free trial  I was just wondering of someone had tried it.

Comment: So, what if someone did try it and it worked. Doesn't guarantee that it will work for you.... (And vice-versa). In any  event, good luck.

Comment: When I used the trial version of webex I could only display my desktop to a number of other people connected to the meeting...I could not change display or give control over to one of the multiple viewers.

Comment: I am not asking if I can give control - I want to know if the other meeting participants can see the other desktop that I am remoted to.

Comment: There's a good chance it would work for me if it did for someone else...

Comment: @tim, did you find a solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: @jaywalker - unfortunately the post I added that answered that question got deleted by a moderator (?!).  I reposted the information.  Hopefully this time it does not get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to work fine, though there is a real lag and jumpiness in the display. I don't think that can be helped.

Comment: This is a re-post of my original answer.  Since it got deleted I am re-posting it as other users wanted to know the results...  if you reinstate the original feel free to delete this.  It would also help to give a reason why a useful post is deleted...

Comment: The fact that another user showed up and ASKED for the answer shows that it is NOT too localized and is appropriate.  It is a useful question to keep active/visible.  Not sure why the moderators are choosing to force the issue here.  It really does not matter to me - I have the answer I need - the issue is one of principle - that the moderators overstepped their bounds and then when called on it they went even more overboard in retribution...

Comment: From an outsiders perspective, I'd say you're too worked up over this (I saw your meta post). If the mods decide to delete something, then that's their decision.  Not a big 
deal.

Comment: I only got worked up when the mods decided to close the question.  the meta post was just a question about why it was closed.  The clear retaliatory closing was what got my hackles up...  It makes no difference to me about this question - I already know the answer.  The only reason i looked at it again was because SO's alerting system showed me the new comment from someone who wanted to know the answer.  Had the mod not deleted it, there would have been no issue.  that is what I was asking about.  then all hell broke loose.

Comment: This is a pretty decent question. The question itself has been upvoted thrice.